# Is there any web application for posting articles to share knowledge, where articles are rated by other users ？

Tags: web-apps, sharing, knowledge-base

It sounds like a blog platform but I don't know which blog platform supports rating. Independent blogs are separated, which is difficult for people to find, and we have no idea about the quality of the blog posts unless we read it.

I think it would be nice if there's a platform that people can share knowledge and experiences, where articles are rated and categorized so that useful articles can be easily found by others by searching.

If there are such web application, please tell me what type the web application is and list the most popular ones.

If there's no such thing, please analyze why it doesn't exist.

Comment: There is an attempt to make such a site for scientific articles [here on stackexchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84646/science-exchange).

Comment: This is so immensely broad, I doubt it exists or will happen. Maybe if you limit yourself (your question) to specific fields.

Comment: Note to all. This question is off-topic here. In fact it is off-topic **everywhere** on S.E. There **is** a proposed new site at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendation  which, if accepted, **will** be the correct place for such questions. So, please go over there and help to get it accepted.

Comment: @Mawg why ? I think it's a valid web application recommendation question

Comment: Because you are asking us to recommend a website, which is not within the terms of the site; we only recommend applications (I **do** hope that you get an answer, but I hope even more that others will help bring the web site recommendations site out of beta).  Perhaps your title is misleading? "Is there any websites ..." instead of "is there any software which I can upload to my site in order to ..."

Comment: @Mawg If I change the title to "Is there any web application...", will it be valid ? and I considered websites/web applications softwares...

Comment: In my opinion, yes, definitely. The difference is that the first asks us to recommend a website (without knowing what software runs it) while the second asks us to recommend some software that you are going to run on your own website. You should make it clear if you are looking for a 3rd party site or some software to host on your own site.

Comment: Isn't software software, regardless of whether it's running on the web stack or the desktop stack?

Comment: @Alex Well, yesnomaybe. Read the lengthy discussion here: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/219/94

Answer (score 1):

[Codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/) allows you to post articles and other users rate them.

From the website:

> CodeProject is comprised of thousands of top-quality programming
>   articles and tutorials. The articles contain hands-on information and
>   are created by guys and girls in the same situations as you. They
>   tackle real-world issues to save you valuable time. Hundreds of new
>   articles are posted each month, as more and more developers come
>   together to share their insight.

For example, these are the top ranked articles ordered by [popularity](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/TopArticles.aspx?ta_so=5), or by [rating](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/TopArticles.aspx?ta_so=1), a functionality required by the orignal poster.

The rules/guidelines on how to submit an article can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/info/Submit.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is related -- I don't know. But what about Reddit? It isn't particularly for articles but many sub Reddits contain articles on various topics and even threads dedicated to useful articles about a certain subjects.

As for voting, Reddit supports the up/down voting of a thread which in turn would up/down vote the article posted within.

I don't know which platform/web application they are using though.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The Reddit software is also sort of open source.